# Correct way of not showing PHP errors but store them in the database

Tags: php, database, config

I have a config to be used in production (not development) PHP site, where I want to hide all PHP errors to the user, but store them in a table in the database. I have the following config, but for some reason if I change the values of the defined constants (customized) to FALSE, I don't get the display error, but neither the database loging:

```
error_reporting(SHOW_E_ALL); // SHOW_E_ALL = 0 for production
ini_set('display_errors', SHOW_ERRORS); // SHOW_ERRORS = FALSE for production
ini_set('display_startup_errors', SHOW_ERRORS); // SHOW_ERRORS = FALSE for production
set_error_handler('myErrorFunction', E_ALL);
```

I have tried different combinations, but I get either the error display in the browser navigator and also the database log of the error, or no display and no log, and never the combination that I want: no display and error log into the database.

Comment: What if your error stems from your database?

Comment: Use try and catch blocs.

Comment: Use try and catch and don't use database for storing error, log your errors in file.

Comment: Well, Drupal stores both error types: code errors (including php warnings and fatal errors) and database errors. And it stores in database. What if you reply to my question instead of circumventing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The display errors properties must be activated, and the customized error-handler function must not display the error and handle properly, I had forgotten not to hide the error print:

```
define("DEBUG", FALSE); // set TRUE for debugging purposes
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); 
set_error_handler('myErrorFunction', E_ALL);

 function myErrorFunction($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
     if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        return;
     }
     $conn = MySQLiConnection::getConnection();

      // insert into database
      ....
      ....
  if(DEBUG){ // if true, it displays the error
     echo "<font color='red'>PHP error in line $errline of file $errfile: " . $errno . " " . str_replace('\\', '/', addslashes($errstr)). '</font>';
  }else{
      // nothing   
  }
    return true;
} // function
```